# Exist some way to use cp for copy a entire folder excluding some files?

Tags: command-line, copy

I've been trying to copy a entire folder to another and this it's simply adding the `-r` option

```
cp -r sourceFolder destFolder
```

But now i need exclude some files from sourceFolder.
How achieve this?

Comment: Excluded files, spread over different directories/levels? Identified by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
for f in sourceFolder/*
do
    if [ "f$" != "filename-to-exclude1" ] || [ "f$" != "filename-to-exclude2" ] # || ...can be extended
    then
        cp -r f$ destinationFolder # this will copy files and folders regardless so if you need to exclude a file from a subfolder you need to extend that if then structure
    fi
done
```